# Regex for numbers between 0-9 and 15 digits as limit

Tags: html

RegEx for only Numbers between 0-9 and 15 digits as limit

Comment: You must first google or search here your questions before posting here there are already a lot of answers available similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following using the [`pattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute) attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]{0,15}$"/>
<input type="text" pattern="^[\d]{0,15}$"/>
```

On the curly brackets `{...}` you can set the min and max length of the input (`{minLength,maxLength}`). To check this you have to make sure the whole value have to be valid. So you have to check completely from start (`^`) to end (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[0-9]{0,15}` or `[\d]{0,15}` which will match all numbers up to fifteen digits in length as defined by the curly brackets.

To apply in html, use the pattern attribute in your input tag:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[\d]{0,15}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ^[0-9]{0,15}$
```

And for match this pattern with your input, use JavaScript match function.